# Error on previously visited page

Tags: oauth, pagereference, session, helper

im having this kind of error. I want my page to redirect to the last valid page it goes to instead of Account-Show. For example, when I click on a product and I decide to Log-in, after successfully logging in I will go directly to the last valid page I visit. My other teammates tried the code and its working but, on my end, I'm receiving this error.
This is the error (edited)

This is from the log error on WebDav

> ERROR
> PipelineCallServlet|1629767718|Sites-Project-Simulation-Site|Account-Login|PipelineCall|QImv6jrJv4
> custom []  Error while executing script
> 'app_storefront_base/cartridge/controllers/Account.js': Wrapped
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: fromIndex = -2
> (app_custom_bootcamp/cartridge/config/oAuthRenentryRedirectEndpoints.js#3)    at
> app_custom_bootcamp/cartridge/config/oAuthRenentryRedirectEndpoints.js:3
> at app_storefront_base/cartridge/scripts/helpers/accountHelpers.js:3
> at app_custom_bootcamp/cartridge/scripts/helpers/accountHelpers.js:3
> at app_storefront_base/cartridge/controllers/Account.js:102
> (anonymous)   at modules/server/route.js:85 (next)    at
> app_storefront_base/cartridge/scripts/middleware/csrf.js:36
> (validateAjaxRequest)     at modules/server/route.js:85 (next)    at
> modules/server/middleware.js:42 (https)   at modules/server/route.js:85
> (next)    at modules/server/middleware.js:27 (post)   at
> modules/server/route.js:93 (anonymous)

This is from the console log on the browser

> Account-Login?rurl=1:1          Failed to load resource: the server
> responded with a status of 500 () DevTools failed to load source map:
> Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND DevTools failed to load source
> map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/config.js.map:
> System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT DevTools failed to load
> source map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gpaiobkfhnonedkhhfjpmhdalgeoebfa/editor/content.js.map:
> System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT main.js:25          POST
> https://zyca-012.sandbox.us03.dx.commercecloud.salesforce.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Project-Simulation-Site/default/Account-Login?rurl=1
> 500

This is my oAuthRenentryRedirectEndpoints.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    1: session.clickStream.clicks.slice(-3)[0].pipelineName,
    2: 'Checkout-Begin',
    3: 'Account-Show'
};
```

This is my accountHelpers.js

```
'use strict';
var URLUtils = require('dw/web/URLUtils');
var base = module.superModule;
var endpoints = require('*/cartridge/config/oAuthRenentryRedirectEndpoints');

/**
 * Creates an account model for the current customer
 * @param {string} redirectUrl - rurl of the req.querystring
 * @param {string} privacyCache - req.session.privacyCache
 * @param {boolean} newlyRegisteredUser - req.session.privacyCache
 * @returns {string} a redirect url
 */
function getLoginRedirectURL(redirectUrl, privacyCache, newlyRegisteredUser) {
  var endpoint = session.clickStream.clicks.slice(-3)[0].pipelineName; // get the endpoint of the pipeline name
  var result;
  // redirect to Account-Show when guest user is on checkout then logs in in confirmation page.
  if (endpoint == 'Order-Confirm') {
    redirectUrl = 3; // Account-Show
  } else {
    redirectUrl = 1; // Pipeline Name
  }
  var targetEndPoint = redirectUrl;


  var argsForQueryString = privacyCache.get();
  argsForQueryString = session.clickStream.clicks.slice(-3)[0].queryString;

  if (targetEndPoint && endpoints[targetEndPoint]) {
      endpoint = endpoints[targetEndPoint];
  }

  if (argsForQueryString) {
      result = URLUtils.url(endpoint, argsForQueryString).relative().toString().replace("%3d", "=").slice(0, -1); // removing unwanted characters in the url
  } else {
      result = URLUtils.url(endpoint).relative().toString();
  }

  return result;
}


module.exports = {
  getLoginRedirectURL: getLoginRedirectURL
};

Object.keys(base).forEach(function (prop) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
  if (!module.exports.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    module.exports[prop] = base[prop];
  }
});
```

What do you think it went wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post error text exclusively as screenshots - among other things, it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. Instead, copy your error text and paste it in the SFSE editor with three a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block for better readability.

Comment: @Moonpie changes have already been made. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: update: it seems that it doesn't record the last valid page i go through(pipelineName) when I log in I run the debugger and instead of an PDP link, it shows Home-Show